# Let $a_n$ be a sequence s.t. $\sum a_n$ converges, let $f:N \rightarrow N$ be a function s.t. $f(n) \rightarrow \infty$.Then $\lim f(n) a_{f(n)} = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to determine whether the following statement is true or false:

Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, and let $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a function s.t. $f(n) \rightarrow \infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) a_{f(n)} = 0$.

I believe this statement is true.

It somewhat reminds Cauchy condensation test, so I tried to take inspiration from its proof but it didn't get me far.

I tried to use the squeeze theorem:

$0 \le f(n) a_{f(n)} \le$ ??

But failed to find an upper bound for the above expression.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the $a_n$s to be decreasing?

Comment: @Mike Thats actually the second part of the question

Comment: What do you mean the second part of the question?

Comment: @Mike There are two questions on my paper, On the second question $a_n$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 16):

This is false. Let $f(n)=n$ for all $n$. Suppose:
\begin{equation}
a_n = 
\begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{n},& \text{$n$ is a square integer}\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then $\sum a_n$ converges but $f(n)a_{f(n)}=1$ whenever $n$ is  a square.

[If you want $a_n$'s to be strictly positive you can simply add $\frac  1{n^{2}}$ to $a_n$ (for each $n$)].

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?

Comment: Too bad one cannot downvote the downvoters.

Comment: Ok thats creative, Thank you.

Comment: If $a_n$ is decreasing then $na_n\to 0,$ as $\sum_{k=[n/2]}^na_k\ge (n/2)a_n.$ In particular $f(n)a_{f(n)}\to 0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, that is a standard result. But OP doesn't want extra assumptions.

Comment: @geetha290krm With no extra assumption the limit can be infinite as there is no monotonicity relation  between $n$ and the value $a_n.$ For instance $a_{2^n}=n^{-2}$ and $a_k=2^{-k}$ for $k\neq 2^n$ and $f(n)=2^n.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Surely we can make the sequence tend to $\infty$ arbitrarily fast.